# Did my question about keyboard mapping get deleted?

Tags: support, off-topic, deleted-questions

I recall asking a question about keyboard mapping when transitioning from linux to mac a few weeks ago. I did get an answer, but I now cannot find the question.

Perhaps I didn't ask it on this forum - but it seems more likely that it was deleted.

Can someone confirm if this is the case - and in which case it was deleted rather than closed?

**Edit:** I've managed to find [my deleted question](https://superuser.com/questions/1517917/what-do-i-need-to-know-about-moving-from-linux-ubuntu-to-macos?noredirect=1#comment2297777_1517917) by scrolling through my inbox notifications.

Question remains as to why this was deleted rather than closed.

As an additional point - my question is hardly an open ended opinion question - it's a specific question about specific, common, hardware/software use cases.

Comment: As an aside to your question being difficult to find, on the questions tab of your profile "activity" page there should be a "recently deleted questions" link at the bottom of the list. It should be to the left side of the list while the page buttons will be on the right. Not the easiest thing to find, and I think it's limited to either 3 or 6 months, but it's hidden in the recesses.

Answer (score 3):

Your question was closed by 5 users as "opinion based" and after 9 days it was deleted by the community "roomba" as part of its cleanup routine

[The Community user deleted my question! What gives?](https://superuser.com/help/roomba)

> If the question was closed more than 9 days ago, and ...
>
> - not closed as a duplicate
> - has a score of 0 or less
> - is not locked
> - has no answers with a score > 0
> - has no accepted answer
> - has no pending reopen votes
> - has not been edited in the past 9 days
>
> ... it will be automatically deleted. These are "abandoned closed", and are termed as `RemoveAbandonedClosed`.

---

As to why it was closed in the first place... after a lot of rambling about keyboard shortcuts you get to the actual question:

> is there a way to fairly seamlessly transition into using MacOS (and VSCode and terminal) from a PC Ubuntu context? What tools/settings should I use, or what should I be aware of?

Is a bit too broad and open ended. How to shift from one operating system to another *from a personal perspective* is a difficult question that is very much centred on the person making the shift and, to a large extent, boils down to "just get on with using it". It is quite simply a problem about retraining muscle-memory.

Being focused on how to train a person out of PC habits and into new Mac based ones also makes it more about humans than computers which again shifts slightly out of our [communities remit](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) which focuses on *computer* hardware and software rather than *biological* hardware and software.

Then there is the final part asking "what tools/settings" to use. Product recommendations are off-topic here as everyone has their favourite tools for particular jobs and often new tools pop up while old tools die. After a time it becomes a popularity contest between tools with the oldest one winning and no real way to judge "best".